# How to rotate text within the HEADERS (Header Text Rotate) in jspdf-autotable?

Tags: javascript, jspdf-autotable

I need to rotate the text of the head text, is there any way we can achieve that. I want to rotate the text within the table header/table body not outside that. I know how to rotate the text by using `doc.text('rotate', 10, 40, { angle: 90 })` for your kind information. Thanks in advance sir.

Answer (score 0):

doc.text("-90 degrees rotated", 20, 160, null, -90);